# Mock calling with return type delegate return test method delegate but not delegates from setup

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

There is a mock for a certain method, in it, depending on the input parameter, I determine which delegate will return. The problem is the following - when this method is called, the delegate set in returns is not called, but the delegate of the TEST method is returned.

How is it?

#### Mock setup

```
actionsProvider
  .Setup(x => x.GetDelegateByCommandNameWithoutParams(It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns((string x) =>
  {
      if (x == testCommand)
         return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>),
             typeof(ExecuteCodeLinesCommandTests).GetMethod(testMethod));
      else if (x == testCommand2)
         return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int, int>),
             typeof(ExecuteCodeLinesCommandTests).GetMethod(testMethod2));
      else return null;

  });
```

#### Mocking interface

```
public interface ICommandActionsProvider
{
   public Delegate? GetDelegateByCommandNameWithoutParams(string commandName);
}
```

#### Method call

```
Delegate? del = commandActionProvider.GetDelegateByCommandNameWithoutParams(commandName);
```

#### Call return TEST method delegate, not from setup

[image: Call return TEST method delegate, not from setup]

I've already tried removing the delegate from returns, leaving just one return value. In this case, mock was called.

Comment: Don't post links to images. Insert them directly instead.

Comment: SNBS, im a new user, stackoverflow wont allow me to insert them directly right now :(

Comment: Ah, sorry then, I forgot about that restriction. FYI: to mention a user write e.g. "@SNBS" (not just "SNBS", as in your comment), and that user will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having branching inside the `Returns` try to create two `Setup`s

```
actionsProvider
  .Setup(x => x.GetDelegateByCommandNameWithoutParams(testCommand))
  .Returns(Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>),
             typeof(ExecuteCodeLinesCommandTests).GetMethod(testMethod)));
```

```
actionsProvider
  .Setup(x => x.GetDelegateByCommandNameWithoutParams(testCommand2))
  .Returns(Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int, int>),
             typeof(ExecuteCodeLinesCommandTests).GetMethod(testMethod2)));
```

If your default mock behaviour is [loose](https://docs.educationsmediagroup.com/unit-testing-csharp/moq/mock-customization) then you will receive `null` for non-matching method calls. (*If it is strict then it will throw exception.*)